# Difference between calling rest client asynchronously with webclient and @Async

Tags: spring-boot, spring-webclient, spring-resttemplate, asyncresttemplate

I am planning to call an web rest endpoint asynchronously. Should i use webclient for all asynchronous invocation. OR can i use rest template and annotate the method with @Async. Will it still be invoked asynchronously.

Wats the differnce between webclient and @async with rest template.